# jQuery offsets & height with the page zoom

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm testing the following for the latest Chrome browser only (need it for my Chrome Extension.)

I was relying on jQuery to get me offsets of DOM elements and their height using the [`offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/), [`outerHeight()`](http://api.jquery.com/outerheight/) and other methods.

This works fine except when the tab/page is zoomed up or down. For some reason those methods return the same values as if no zooming was done.

Do I need to use other functions to account for the page zoom?

Comment: Include all the code you are using. Otherwise it is not hard to find your error. I guess you are assigning the values to a global variable.

Comment: jQuery docs: _"Also, dimensions may be incorrect when the page is zoomed by the user; browsers do not expose an API to detect this condition."_

Comment: There are methods coming to extension APIs to get zoom information, but the milestone is Chrome 38.

Comment: @Xan: Yeah, I'm surprised that nether Chrome nor jQuery had any means of determining page zoom. What worked for me though was to get zoom using this method/hack and then multiply/divide the results returned by jQuery functions: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16091319/843732